# calling functions in python

Tags: python, function

I have two functions "a" and "b".  "b" gets called when a user uploads a file. "b" renames the file and returns the new filename. After that the file is supposed to be edited. Like this:

```
def a():
    edits file

def b():
    renames file  
    return file
```

So if b happens and ends, a is supposed to happen. Once "b" `returns file` the function is over and nothing happens after. Exactly at this point I want "a" to happen, how is this possible? Right now I call "a" with a timer

```
t=Timer(1.0,a)
t.start()
```

but that's not a good solution. I tried with global variables but it doesn't work. I also tried `return file, a()` cause I thought then a would maybe get started. 
Is there something like `if b(): a()` ?

Anyone a suggestion?

Comment: `b(); a()` runs `a` after `b` finishes. I think you meant to ask something different here; please clarify.

Comment: No, I meant to ask two functions, one returns something that the other function needs, therefore, the second function a() has to run after b

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `a` in `b`:

```
def b():
    ...
    a()

def a():
    ...

b()
```

Comment: yes, i tried but b returns a value that is needed in a, so if i call a before b returns the value a wont work

Answer (score 1):

Call `a()` in the `b` definition:

```
def a(file):
   ## edit_file

def b(file):
   ## rename_file 
   a(file)
   return file
```

Comment: b returns a value that is needed in a, so if i call a before b returns the value a wont work

Comment: @klausruprecht Just pass the value as an argument in `a`. check the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily call `a()` from within `b()`, and you can make it so that it will only be called if `b` ran successfully with multiple return points.

```
def a():
    something

def b():
    something
    if something goes wrong:
        return None or someError
    something
    a()
    return correct result
```

Only one `return`will ever run, so if you're testing and find that `b` did not run successfully, you can return a value (or nothing) prematurely so that it never reaches the point where `a` is called.

Comment: but that means if something does not go wrong the value will be created at the end of b(), a() however needs the value in advance

Comment: In what way? Does `a` need the value passed or for `b` to modify a global value?

Comment: file gets uploaded => b() gets called, b() renames file, a() edits file (that's why a() needs the value of b()

Comment: So does a need the new filename or is it dependent on the file itself being changed? In the latter case it works fine to just call a right at the end. In the former case you can just pass the filename to a.

Comment: Ohh, I see so in b: 
a(filename)
return filename 
and then def a(filename): ?